# SPF Limits and SPF Merging

Tags: email, email-server, spf, mx-record, email-bounces

I am using Zoho Mail, AWS SES, GMAIL SMTP, Cloudflare email route and Yahoo SMTP. they all have there own SPF record. i saw on Google the `only 1 SPF should be added in hostname` and `maximum 10 SPF hostname is supported in 1 SPF record`.

I am trying to merge and which is the correct one?

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.mx.cloudflare.net include:zoho.in include:_spf.google.com include:_spf.mail.yahoo.com ~all
```

or

```
v=spf1 a mx include:_spf.mx.cloudflare.net include:zoho.in include:_spf.google.com include:_spf.mail.yahoo.com ~all
```

or

```
v=spf1 a mx include:_spf.mx.cloudflare.net include:zoho.in include:_spf.google.com include:_spf.mail.yahoo.com -all
```

**Errors i am getting when i am testing with `mail-tester.com`.**

Error 1 : `Maximum DNS-interactive terms limit (10) exceeded`

Error 2 : `example.com: Sender is not authorized by default to use 'user@example.com' in 'mfrom' identity, however domain is not currently prepared for false failures (mechanism '~all' matched)`

Comment: Which record are you using to generate the report? Also, the last two of the three are identical.

Comment: @Paul `mail-tester.com` for testing the mail and errors. and all 3 records are different.

Comment: You probably don't need the `A` and `MX` mechanisms, unless you have a mail server that uses the same IP address for Sending and Receiving. Those mechanisms usually come from examples ESPs use. Wether to use `soft fail` (`~all`) or `fail` (`-all`) in the catch all is a personal choice. If you rely on DMARC, I'd suggest to use `~all`, to not junk forwarded emails failing SPF.

Comment: As for the 10-lookup-limit, you could consider using subdomains for authenticating SPF. i.e. many services allow you to send from me@mydomain.com, while setting the bounce address (`Return-Path` header) to bounces@SUB.mydomain.com, on which the SPF check is done.

Comment: The first record has two more DNS lookups than the other two. The DNS lookups for the last two are identical. Changing the mechanisms does nothing to change DNS lookups.

Comment: @Paul Well, the question is about merging as well as about limits (errors). I imagine service A includes in their example `v=spf1 A MX include:_spf.serviceA.com -all`, while Service B includes in their example `v=spf1 MX include:_spf.ServiceB.com ~all` and Service C includes in their example `v=spf1 include:_spf.serviceC.com ~all`.